# Proxying Docker Containers as Subdomains

Tags: proxy, docker

I'm looking to proxy docker containers as subdomains of the docker host as below. I've seen several solutions that can accomplish something similar, but none really fit our need.

**Host Machine: Corporate VPS running RHEL 7.2**

- Host Domain: host.net (fakename - but it's behind a corporate intranet, not reachable from public)
- DNS Server: DNS for host.net is delegated to the host machine, so I need to run a dns server on :53 (this is new, which is why one isn't already setup)
- Host IP: 172.16.10.12

**Docker: v1.10**

- Subnet: dockernet 192.168.222.1/24
- Subnet dns (docker created): dnsmasq on 192.168.122.1:53

**Goal:**

- dnsmasq on host machine to serve host.net from 172.16.10.12
- proxy all subdomains (*.host.net) to subnet dockernet so that any container joined to dockernet would be reachable by containername.host.net, containerhostname.host.net, alias1.host.net, etc.
- have this happen automatically for any container that connects to dockernet
- to have containers treated as hosts so we don't have to manually open up ports through docker: ex: rediscontainer.host.net:6379

**Questions / Issues:**

- can't start dnsmasq on host machine because docker has already bound 192.168.122.1:53 - I believe I can configure dnsmasq to not listen on a specific IP, but I'm new to this
- what's a relatively easy way to configure this? I was hoping I could configure dnsmasq and iptables to do this, but I'm not sure how to go about it, or if these two could accomplish my goal.
- I assume that docker's built in dns for user defined networks is the easiest way to automate container name resolution, but is there an easier way?
  My apologies for any ambiguity as I'm new to dns, subnets, etc. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Eric

Answer (score 1):

I implemented such dynamic subdomains per containers using [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy).

[This article](https://blog.confirm.ch/docker-reverse-proxy/) also explains how to achieve the same from nginx base image and dockergen to generate nginx conf from docker events.